# "Excellent" Charge Moves in PvP

Tags: pokemon-go

In Trainer Battles (Arena, Rocket fights, etc), you can "charge" a move by swiping all of the icons that appear. Depending on how many you hit, you can get a caption showing how well you did; "Nice", "Great", or "Excellent", much like when you catch Pokémon.

When catching a Pokémon, this affects the "strength" of your catch. E.g a "Great" throw is better than a "Nice" throw, which will increase the likelihood of catching the Pokémon. However, I haven't seen much difference for the Charged Moves in Trainer Battles.

So, in Trainer Battles, when executing a Charged Move, is there any difference between "Nice", "Great", and "Excellent", and if so, what effect does it have exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 'Excellent' Charged Attacks are more powerful

Completing the charge attack mini-game by swiping around hitting all the circles/bubbles, increases the 'power' of the attack. That is to say, an 'Excellent' charged attack will remove more HP from the opposing Pokemon, than if the same Pokemon used the same charged attack but ending up with 'Nice' or 'Great'.

The [Pokemon Go Wikia article on Attacks](https://pokemongo.fandom.com/wiki/Attacks#Charged_attacks) explains it (emphasis mine):

> In Trainer Battles, GO Battle League matches and battles against Team GO Rocket members, when Trainer uses the one of Battle Minigames is initiated. **The bonus power of the Charged Attack depends on the player's performance in these minigames.**

Comment: I don't have a source, but I believe I read somewhere that hitting all the bubbles in the mini-game will lead to the charge move doing twice as much damage compared to if you hit none of the bubbles, with the damage scaling linearly from minimum to maximum for each bubble hit.

Comment: @Kadima I remember reading this somewhere too but I also haven't been able to confirm it yet.